# Excel: Match returns a wrong row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I am using a rather simple match function, yet I cannot seem to understand why is it returning the wrong row number. You can see in the screenshot that the row is 111, yet match returns 113.

Any ideas?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmDtm.png)

Comment: Check the value in 111, maybe there is a leading or following Space or an other not printable charakter…

Comment: Using XMATCH defaults to exact match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually, this is because you did not specify you want an exact match and your data is not sorted

Comment: Thanks King @Dirk, exact match is indeed the fix here!